# SSJS rows.retrieve returns null

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am trying to print the JSON values from the Rows.Retrieve function of SSJS but it always returns null

```
var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("DE's External Key");
var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();
var newString = JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t');
Write("The Value " + newString );
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, I usually just call the [Stringify()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityStringify.htm) function from the Platform Functions of SSJS directly and check for a typeof 'Object' and length before I do anything with the response data.

I have not tested the below but it should work assuming the Data Extension External Key is correct and located within the same Business Unit you are executing the SSJS.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load('core', '1');

    var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init("DE's External Key");
    var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();

    if (typeof(data) == 'object' && data.length > 0) {
      Write("The Value " + Stringify(data));
    } else {
      Write("No Rows Found");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help 